# Why does Stan Lee make a cameo in The Princess Diaries 2?

Tags: cameo, stan-lee, the-princess-diaries-2

[image]

**Transcription:**

> Why did Stan Lee make a cameo in The Princess Diaries 2? Was this foreshadowing Disney buying Marvel? Is Princess Mia going to be an Avenger? So many questions

We all know Stan Lee makes cameos in many of the Marvel superhero films. Even his [cameo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zInRAarZnZ0) as a [bus driver](http://heroeswiki.com/Stan_Lee) in *Heroes* makes a little sense because of the comicbook superhero connection. Why does he cameo in *The Princess Diaries 2*? **Have either Stan Lee, Marvel, or the filmmakers commented as to why Lee make a cameo  in *The Princess Diaries 2*?**

Answer (score 12):

## No obvious connection, but this is actually not unusual.

While it seems that Stan Lee has a personal connection to the projects in which he makes a cameo appearance, as enforced by his appearances in the Sony Spider-Man productions, the X-Men Cinematic Universe, and of course the ever-expanding Marvel Cinematic Universe, he actually has a history of cameo'ing in things that have no strong or obvious connection to him, such as:

- *The Simpsons*
- *Superman: The Animated Series* (really!)
- *Nikita* (TV series)
- *Big Bang Theory*
- *Chuck*

And of course, *Princess Diaries 2*.

[image]

After much searching and cross-referencing, I can find no obvious connection between Stan Lee and any cast or crew on *Princess Diaries 2*, but the above sampling of his cameos suggests that there doesn't *need to be*.

Comment: The Simpsons and Big Bang Theory have a habit of inviting celebrities on to do cameos. No real connection is required there.

Comment: Muppet Babies was produced by Marvel Animation

Comment: "*Lee's Nikita cameo came about when the show's star, Maggie Q, met Lee at San Diego Comic-Con in July and the two discussed the possibility of Lee appearing on the show. With Lee in Toronto (where Nikita films) for Fan Expo this past weekend, the timing worked out for him to also film a scene for the TV series.*" - http://uk.ign.com/articles/2010/08/31/stan-lee-takes-on-nikita

Comment: @Richard : Inviting a random celebrity or bumping into another celebrity at a convention are the sorts of tenuous connection I'm talking about.  (But I'll remove Muppet Babies because of the Marvel connection.)  The reason he was on *Princess Diaries 2* seems to fall on the tenuous side, and no one has made a great effort to document the circumstances that led to it.  :-)

Comment: I don't think "he was offered money to appear and he appeared" is exactly a cameo.

Comment: @Richard : [Cameo *n.*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cameo): a minor part played by a prominent performer in a single scene of a motion picture or a television play.

Comment: In both cases they were more like special guests.

Answer (score 3):

After a whole bunch of IMDb digging, the nearest I can guess is that he was cast by [director Garry Marshall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368933/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm). The movie shares no casting or producing credits with a Marvel movie before or after 2004.

It seems that in 2010 Garry Marshall was in [*With Great Power: The Stan Lee Story*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1091863/?ref_=nm_flmg_slf_25), and all of the people interviewed for the movie have worked with Stan Lee previously.

Now the timeline seems that it could be that Garry is talking in 2010 about Stan Lees 2004 cameo in Princess Diaries 2, however it seems odd that he would cameo with no prior connection.

Comment: Actually, not odd at all.  He has cameo'ed in various things that he has no connection to....

Comment: Why was this deleted? It seems like a reasonable answer.