# What cameos has Stan Lee had?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, cameo, stan-lee

It's well known that Stan Lee has had many cameo appearances. He has been in every [Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) film, [played himself on The Simpsons](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Stan_Lee), and even [appeared in Princess Diaries 2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/why-does-stan-lee-make-a-cameo-in-the-princess-diaries-2).

How many films has Stan Lee been in? Is there a full list of cameos anywhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Stan Lee has a LONG history of cameos dating back 30-40 years.

---

#### [Spider-Man and His Amazing Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_His_Amazing_Friends) - 7 Little Superheroes [[S1 Ep6](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796528/)] (October 1981)

While not *technically* a cameo, Stan Lee narrated the sixth episode of the animated series *Spider-Man and His Amazing Friends* in 1981.

[image: Title card for 7 Little Superheroes]

---

#### [The Trial of the Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial_of_the_Incredible_Hulk) (May 1989)

Stan Lee's first live-action cameo is in a TV film based on the [1978 Incredible Hulk TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(1978_TV_series)). Bruce Banner is wrongly on trial for sexual assault and is being defended in court by Matt Murdock (Daredevil).

Stan appears as a jury member when Hulk transforms and tears the room apart.

[image: Stan Lee in The Trial of the Incredible Hulk]

---

#### [Jim Henson's Muppet Babies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Henson%27s_Muppet_Babies) - Comic Capers [S6 Ep6] (October 1989)

Appears as himself alongside Spider-Man.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/DTjBnFXMg3I?t=160))

[image: Stan Lee in Muppet Babies]

---

#### [Mallrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallrats) (October 1995)

Stan Lee gives romantic advice in what is supposedly [his favorite movie appearance of all time](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2016/06/19/stan-lee-picks-kevin-smiths-mallrats-as-favorite-movie-hes-been-/).

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFLlwtqHINs))

[image: Stan Lee in Mallrats]

---

#### [Spider-Man: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)) - Spider-Wars Part 2 [[S5 Ep13](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_The_Animated_Series_Season_5_13)] (January 1998)

In the show's final episode, Spider-Man travels to a dimension where he is a fictional superhero and Stan Lee is his creator. He uses his webslingers to give Stan a ride around town and chat before leaving him on top of a building and returning to his own universe.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N9TIvIEnpA))

[image: Stan Lee in Spider-Man the Animated Series]

---

#### [Superman: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_The_Animated_Series) - Apokolips... Now! Part 2 [[S2 Ep26](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Apokolips..._Now!)] (February 1998)

Yes, you read that correctly.

In the episode's original TV broadcast, Dan Turpin's funeral contained cameos from multiple Marvel characters and employees, including Captain America, Tony Stark, Nick Fury, and of course, Stan Lee. These cameos were removed for the episode's DVD release.

[image: Stan Lee in Superman: the Animated Series]

---

#### [X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(film)) (July 2000)

Stan Lee plays a hot dog vendor seen after Senator Robert Kelly emerges from the sea after escaping Magneto.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nskvUlDwaiA))

[image: Stan Lee in X-Men]

---

#### [The Simpsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons) - I Am Furious (Yellow) [[S13 Ep18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Furious_(Yellow))] (April 2002)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVYYpECTuvM))

[image: Stan Lee in The Simpsons]

---

#### [Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2002_film)) (May 2002)

Lee saves a young girl from falling debris during Spider-Man's fight with the Green Goblin.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/XyBU3YIugW0?t=24))

In a deleted scene, he also plays a street vendor who tries to sell Peter Parker a pair of sunglasses.

---

#### [Daredevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(film)) (February 2003)

In a deleted scene, a young Matt Murdock saves an oblivious Stan Lee from walking into traffic.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpS7iFIFcJs))

[image: Stan Lee in Daredevil]

---

#### [Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(film)) (June 2003)

In his first live-action speaking role, Stan Lee plays a security guard talking with Hulk's original TV actor Lou Ferrigno.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjMMayhbAFc))

[image: Stan Lee in Hulk]

---

#### [Spider-Man 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2) (June 2004)

Stan Lee once again plays a random bystander. This time, he saves a woman from being crushed by rubble while Spider-Man fights Doctor Octopus.

[image: Stan Lee in Spider Man 2]

In a deleted scene, Lee has another cameo, saying "Look, Spider-Man stole that kid's sneakers."

---

#### [The Princess Diaries 2: Royal Engagement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Diaries_2:_Royal_Engagement) (August 2004)

If you're going to ask why Stan Lee is in Princess Diaries 2, [someone's already asked that question for you](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/why-does-stan-lee-make-a-cameo-in-the-princess-diaries-2).

The answer? [We have no idea.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/55148/48480)

[image: Stan Lee in The Princess Diaries 2]

---

#### [Man-Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Thing_(film)) (April 2005)

A photo of Stan Lee is seen on a board of missing people.

[image: Stan Lee in Man-Thing]

---

#### [Fantastic Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2005_film)) (July 2005)

Stan Lee plays Reed Richards' mailman, [Willie Lumpkin](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Willie_Lumpkin).

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=damX80VyiO0))

[image: Stan Lee in Fantastic Four]

---

#### [X-Men: The Last Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_The_Last_Stand) (May 2006)

Jean Grey's powers affects gravity in the surrounding area, including Stan Lee's garden hose.

[image: Stan Lee in X-Men: The Last Stand]

---

#### Heroes - Unexpected [[S1 Ep16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_(Heroes))] (February 2007)

Stan Lee plays a truck driver.

[image: Stan Lee in Heroes]

---

#### [Spider-Man 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_3) (April 2007)

While looking at a sign reading 'Spider-man To Receive Key To The City', Stan tells Peter Parker, "You know, I guess one person can make a difference... Nuff said."

[image: Stan Lee in Spider-Man 3]

---

#### Robot Chicken - Tapping a Hero [[S3 Ep4](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1096316/)]  (September 2007)

[image: Stan Lee in Robot Chicken - Tapping a Hero]

---

#### [Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four:_Rise_of_the_Silver_Surfer) (June 2007)

Stan tries to attend Reed Richards and Sue Storm's wedding, but is turned away when the bouncer doesn't believe him when he says he's Stan Lee.

[image: Stan Lee in Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer]

---

#### [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(2008_film)) (May 2008)

Tony Stark mistakes Stan Lee for Hugh Hefner at a party.

[image: Stan Lee in Iron Man]

In an alternate version of the scene, Lee replies "That's okay, I get this all the time."

---

#### [The Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(film)) (June 2008)

Dies after being poisoned by green soda containing Bruce Banner's blood.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehAkYxYze7M))

[image: Stan Lee in The Incredible Hulk]

---

#### The Spectacular Spider-Man - Blueprints [S2 Ep1] (January 2009)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08u7hiRBzMU))

[image: Stan Lee in The Spectacular Spider-Man]

---

#### The Big Bang Theory - The Excelsior Acquisition [[S3 Ep16](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Excelsior_Acquisition)] (March 2010)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTaHDiuuZjk))

[image: Stan Lee in The Big Bang Theory]

---

#### Heroman [S1 Ep1] (April 2010)

Not only did Stan Lee cameo in an anime he helped write, he managed to [create a brand new meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/stan-lee-asking-for-coffee) in the process.

[image: Stan Lee in Heroman]

---

#### [Iron Man 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_2) (May 2010)

In a callback to Iron Man 1, Tony Stark mistakes Stan Lee for Larry King at a party.

[image: Stan Lee in Iron Man 2]

---

#### Nikita - The Guardian [[S1 Ep5](http://nikita2010.wikia.com/wiki/The_Guardian)] (October 2010)

Appears as Hank Excelsior, witness to a bank robbery who is interviewed by a TV reporter.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRsSepVXGwI))

[image: Stan Lee in Nikita]

---

#### [Pizza Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_Man_(2011_film)) (2011)

Appears as himself in a cameo so obscure, I couldn't find what month the film was released.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD1lCGgoTKo))

[image: Stan Lee in Pizza Man]

---

#### [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(film)) (May 2011)

"Stan the Man" unsuccessfully tries to move Thor's hammer with his pickup truck.

[image: Stan Lee in Thor]

---

#### [Captain America: The First Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger) (July 2011)

An elderly general who mistakes a another man for Captain America/Steve Rogers, commenting  "I thought he'd be taller."

[image: Stan Lee in Captain America: The First Avenger]

---

#### [Chuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_(TV_series)) - Chuck Versus the Santa Suit [[S5 Ep7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2073186/)] (December 2011)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcKMLPB-Z4E))

[image: Stan Lee in Chuck]

---

#### [The Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(2012_film)) (May 2012)

After the battle of New York City, Stan Lee is seen on TV playing chess as part of an interview. He dismisses the idea of super heroes existing in New York.

[image: Stan Lee in The Avengers]

Stan Lee also appears in a deleted scene where he encourages Steve Rogers to ask a waitress for her number.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Pov4qMSfg9w?t=111))

---

#### [Ultimate Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man_(TV_series)) - Great Power [[S1 Ep1](http://thedailybugle.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Power)] (April 2012)

According to the [Ultimate Spider-Man Wiki](http://thedailybugle.wikia.com/wiki/Stan#Appearances), Stan Lee has appeared in no less than 13 episodes of Ultimate Spider-Man as [Stan the Janitor](http://thedailybugle.wikia.com/wiki/Stan). He is secretly one of the original members of S.H.I.E.L.D.

---

#### [Robot Chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Chicken) - Executed by the State [[S6 Ep1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2138969/)] (September 2012)

---

#### [The Amazing Spider-Man (Video Game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_video_game)) - [Stan Lee Adventure Pack DLC](http://amazingspiderman.wikia.com/wiki/Stan_Lee_Adventure_Pack) (June 2012)

Play as Stan Lee and use Spider-Man's web slinging powers to track down the missing pages for Stan's latest comic book script.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-NhCTMVPRc))

---

#### [The Amazing Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_film)) (July 2012)

An unobservant librarian at the Midtown Science High School listening to music as Spider-Man fights The Lizard Dr. Curt Connors in the background.

[image: Stan Lee in The Amazing Spider-Man]

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZapELQXx9LM))

---

#### Robot Chicken - Robot Fight Accident [[S6 Ep18](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2674382/)] (February 2013)

---

#### [Iron Man 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3) (May 2013)

Beauty pageant judge on TV who happily gives one of the contestants a 10.

[image: Stan Lee in Iron Man 3]

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xw1xLc7etaI))

---

#### [Phineas and Ferb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb) - Mission Marvel [[S4 Ep16 & 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb:_Mission_Marvel)] (August 2013)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICJxCbWIZtc))

---

#### [Thor: The Dark World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_The_Dark_World) (November 2013)

Lee appears as a mental ward patient who loans his shoe to Erik Selvig for a demonstration about "the Convergence" in his delusions. When Selvig finishes and asks if anyone has questions, Lee says, "Yeah, can I have my shoe back"?

[image: Stan Lee in Thor: The Dark World]

---

#### The Simpsons - Married to the Blob [[S25 Ep10](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Married_to_the_Blob)] (January 2014)

[image: Stan Lee in The Simpsons]

---

#### [Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D.) - T.R.A.C.K.S. [[S1 Ep13](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/T.R.A.C.K.S.)] (February 2014)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1l8iaCK-h8))

---

#### [Captain America: The Winter Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier) (April 2014)

Lee plays a security guard at the Smithsonian Institution who after discovering that Captain America stole his own World War II uniform from an exhibit, says, "Oh man, I am so fired."

[image: Stan Lee in Captain America: The Winter Soldier]

---

#### [The Amazing Spider-Man 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_2) (May 2014)

A guest at Peter Parker and Gwen Stacy's graduation. Mentions that he recognises Peter Parker.

[image: Stan Lee in The Amazing Spider-Man 2]

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXHssADhjM4))

---

#### [The Amazing Spider-Man 2 (Video Game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_2_(2014_video_game)) (May 2014)

One mission has Spider-Man saving Stan Lee from a burning building, followed by a visit to his comic book shop.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/3N3XjcPNgfI?t=40))

[image: Stan Lee in Amazing Spider-Man 2 Video Game]

---

#### [Guardians of the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(film)) (August 2014)

Rocket Racoon notices Stan flirting with alien women on Xandar.

[image: Stan Lee in Guardians of the Galaxy]

---

#### [Big Hero 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hero_6_(film)) (November 2014)

Revealed to be Fred's father in a post-credits scene.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKG_L-fDk8U))

---

#### [Agent Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Carter_(TV_series)) - The Blitzkrieg Button [[S1 Ep4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blitzkrieg_Button)] (January 2015)

Has his shoes shined while sitting next to Howard Stark.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px_QSaoWez4))

---

#### Daredevil [[S1 Ep13](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Daredevil_(episode)) & [S2 Ep2](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Dogs_to_a_Gunfight)]/Jessica Jones [[S1 Ep7](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/AKA_Top_Shelf_Perverts)]/Luke Cage [[S1 Ep12](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Soliloquy_of_Chaos)]/Iron Fist [[S1 Ep13](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Plays_with_Fire)] (April 2015 to Present)

Senior NYPD officer [Irving Forbush](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Irving_Forbush). He has appeared on an NYPD poster in [every Netflix MCU series to date.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/70597/48480)

[image: Stan Lee on a poster in Daredevil]

---

#### [Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron) (May 2015)

Appears as a military veteran at the Avengers' victory party. He claims he fought at Omaha Beach and that it proves he can handle a shot of Asgardian liquor from Thor, but is then carried away drunk, muttering his catchphrase, "Excelsior!"

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czCr113i0SU))

---

#### [Ant Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_(film)) (July 2015)

Bartender seen during Luis' flashback of Falcon looking for Ant-Man in a post-credits scene.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/PVeA9uZbQYY?t=23))

---

#### [Lego Marvel's Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Marvel%27s_Avengers) (January 2016)

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqJ9I8nws6M))

---

#### [Yoga Hosers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Hosers) (January 2016)

Appears as a police officer.

---

#### [Stan Lee's Lucky Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee%27s_Lucky_Man) - More Yang Than Yin [S1 Ep1] (January 2016)

Appears as himself signing autographs.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE6qrsVCYB8&t=5s))

---

#### [Deadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)) (February 2016)

Stan appears as a strip club D.J. in the nightclub where Wade Wilson's/Deadpool's girlfriend Vanessa works.

---

#### [Captain America: Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War) (April 2016)

FedEx delivery man mistaking Tony Stark for "Tony Stank".

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYM8Vrthhvw))

---

#### [X-Men: Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse) (May 2016)

Lee is shown viewing the rising nuclear weapons launched by Apocalypse next to his wife Joan.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddNoSeLgxyE))

---

#### [Doctor Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(film)) (October 2016)

Bus passenger reading [The Doors of Perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doors_of_Perception) by [Aldous Huxley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldous_Huxley).

[image: Stan Lee in Doctor Strange]

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXtPC1kGp1s))

---

#### [Logan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan_(film)) (March 2017)/Deadpool 2 'No Good Deed' Teaser

In a teaser for Deadpool 2 that played before Logan (2017), Deadpool tells Stan Lee to shut up after being complimented on his superhero costume.

([Watch on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Z5ezsReZcxU?t=117))

---

#### [The Simpsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons) - The Caper Chase [[S28 Ep18](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Caper_Chase)] (April 2017)

Stan Lee makes a brief cameo in the opening couch gag.

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFgGT2OQDvk))

---

#### [Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2) (May 2017)

Appears as an informant to the Watchers.

---

#### [The Gifted](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0498278/#actor) - Pilot Episode eXposed (Oct 2017)

Eclipse passes him through a doorway going into a bar, The Texas Lounge.

---

Fun bonus video: Stan Lee's Cameo School

([Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbJrvO0MsgQ))

---

I'm sure I've missed at least a few cameos. ([The guy has over 106 actor credits on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0498278/#actor)).  Feel free to edit in any I've missed.

Comment: I think some of those are just normal roles not cameos . Also you forgot one! https://youtu.be/iE6qrsVCYB8?t=5s

Comment: If anybody get free enough time to edit: [Wikipedia: Stan Lee cameos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee_cameos) and also he shot [more cameo for 6 unreleased films](https://www.inverse.com/article/50756-stan-lee-cameo-avengers-4-captain-marvel)